# Merge chemical leavening tags

Tags: discussion, retagging, suggestion

I suggest that the two tags [baking-soda](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking-soda) and [baking-powder](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baking-powder) be merged as synonyms into a single [chemical-leavening](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-leavening).

Neither has any followers at this time.

Comment: Looks like 3 questions are tagged with both, and another 9 baking soda and 14 baking powder. Have you seen a lot of confusion between the two in the questions tagged with just one? Generally more specific tags are better, as long as they're not so specific as to be meaningless.

Comment: My thinking is that is not very many questions, and it is a single subject where questions usually need to address both, or the differences between them.  I think specific tags are only useful if there is a sufficient volume of questions.

Answer (score 5):

The trouble with this, in my mind, is that the majority of members won't *find* a tag called "chemical leavening" because they don't think in those terms. And if people can't find the appropriate tag for their question, then they add inappropriate tags instead.

I'm not saying it isn't *correct* - it *is* the correct umbrella term. I just don't see any pressing need to merge them or any obvious advantage to using a more generic term. People aren't getting the two confused, and lots of questions really *are* specific to one or the other (since they aren't actually interchangeable).

We can have [chemical-leavening](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-leavening) as a tag *as well*, sort of like we have [gelling-agents](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelling-agents) in addition to [gelatin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelatin) and [pectin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pectin) (interestingly, [gelatin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelatin) is the far more frequently-used tag, which further reinforces my previous point about discoverability). I don't imagine it will get heavy use at this point, though.

I would suggest leaving those two tags alone and manually-retagging as [chemical-leavening](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-leavening) the ones that are truly about the general concept.

Comment: Mostly what your argument shows is a weakness in the SE tag system, in that they are not heirarchical by nature, and selecting the leaf one implies all of the parents.   That is why I was suggesting leaving the original terms as synonyms.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: That's [not as great as it sounds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/141911). The idea of clusters, as opposed to hierarchy, could work, but the SE team seems to think that "Filtered Questions" feature on [Stack Exchange Home](http://stackexchange.com/) is a perfectly good substitute (I don't agree, just explaining the situation).

Comment: I probably am that obsessive as the evidence shows, but I am just too tired to wade through all the stuff in that link.   :-)